# What are %O and %S in platex -synctex=1 -halt-on-error -file-line-error %O %S

Tags: latexmk, perl

I installed LaTeX with brew:

```
# macOS MacTex Install
$ brew cask install mactex-no-gui

# Updating the packages
$ sudo tlmgr update --self && sudo tlmgr update --all

$ latex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)
kpathsea version 6.3.2
...
$ latexmk --version
Latexmk, John Collins, 29 September 2020. Version 4.70b
$ platex --version
e-pTeX 3.14159265-p3.8.3-191112-2.6 (utf8.euc) (TeX Live 2020)
kpathsea version 6.3.2
...
```

I also had to add PATH to .zshrc.

```
export PATH="/Library/TeX/texbin/:$PATH"
```

I have the following in .latexmkrc file for LaTeX. I have no experience with Perl.

```
...
$latex = 'platex -synctex=1 -halt-on-error -file-line-error %O %S';
$max_repeat = 5;
...
```

Q1. What is %O %S?

Q2. I change the `platex` to `latex` and `pdflatex`, but both give errors.
`platex` is for Japanese language.
How can I change `platex` using `latex` or `pdflatex`?

```
# not working
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex -synctex=1 -halt-on-error -file-line-error %O %S';
```

And log output:

> LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> L3 programming layer <2020-10-05> xparse
> <2020-03-03>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/platex/jsclasses/jsarticle.cls
>
> /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/platex/jsclasses/jsarticle.cls:14:
> LaTeX Error: This file needs format `pLaTeX2e' but this is` LaTeX2e'. ...

Why is it using platex? I never set it up using platex.

Q3. How to change the preferences in mactex no gui?

Comment: `%O` and `%S` are placeholders for options and source (see the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/latexmk/latexmk.pdf)). Why `latex` and `pdflatex` throw errors is hard to tell when you don't show the error messages...

Comment: The error says clearly, that you need `platex` for that kind of document.